# C# 'Class' is a type, not valid in the given context when write factory method with generics

Tags: generics, c#-4.0, design-patterns

I am finding difficult to create a factory method to return the following base class:

```
public sealed class ClassA : GeneratedMessage<ClassA, ClassA.Builder>{}
public sealed class ClassB : GeneratedMessage<ClassB, ClassB.Builder>

public abstract class GeneratedMessage<TMessage, TBuilder> : AbstractMessage<TMessage, TBuilder>
        where TMessage : GeneratedMessage<TMessage, TBuilder>
        where TBuilder : GeneratedBuilder<TMessage, TBuilder>, new()
        {
        }

public class EventFactory
{

    public GeneratedMessage<TMessage, TBuilder> GetEvent<TMessage, TBuilder>(int typeId)
            where TMessage : GeneratedMessage<TMessage, TBuilder>
            where TBuilder : GeneratedBuilder<TMessage, TBuilder>, new()
    {
        switch(typeId)
        {
            case 1:
                ClassA
                beak;
            case 2:
                ClassB
        }
    }
}
```

How to write so that i can return ClassA if 1 and ClassB if 2?

When i use return ClassA or ClassB in factory method, i am getting 'ClassA is a type', which is not valid in the given context.

Thanks

Comment: From your example you're listing the type name of ClassA and ClassB when you need to be returning an instance. How will you generate the instance? (e.g. "return new ClassA();"

Comment: because the classes are sealed we can't return new

Comment: You can create an instance of a sealed class, just not an abstract class. Sealed means you can't inherit from the class. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx

Comment: You can't. Your method is expected to return an open generic, not a closed generic.

Comment: @AdrianIftode, would you mind direct me with some sample code or some example about how to return an open generic as in my case? Thanks

Comment: The open generic should also inherit GeneratedMessage. With ClassA and ClassB you made it a closed one.  Please check some articles that explain the difference and you will know what you have to return.

Answer (score 0):

The `GetEvent` method signature should return objects of this type `GeneratedMessage<TMessage, TBuilder>`, but you are trying to return objects of `ClassA` and `ClassB` types. A client of this method expects to retrieve any form of an `GeneratedMessage<TMessage, TBuilder>` and not its closed variations (ClassA, ClassB, .. ClassN).

So either you make ClassA and ClassB as open generics like:

```
public sealed class ClassA<TMessage, TBuilder> : GeneratedMessage<TMessage, TBuilder>{}
```

And yo can use them like

```
switch(typeId)
    {
        case 1:
            return new ClassA<TMessage, TBuilder>();
        case 2:
            return new ClassB<TMessage, TBuilder>();
    }
```

Or you don't use this `GetEvent` method as a generic one. You define a common interface for ClassA and ClassB, implement that interface and change the `GetEvent` signature to use that interface.

Comment: Thanks. But i can't edit the Class A or Class B as it is from another library which i dont own.

Comment: Create an adapter.

Comment: Sorry to say that I haven't worked on any design pattern like Adapter. Can you provide me some link with some example for my problem :(